# WCF library contract into WCF Application

Tags: wcf, entity, wcf-library

So, I'm new in WCF and haven't completely imagined how is it working..
I have a solution with several projects: `EntityModelProject`, `WCFLibraryProject` and `WCFProject`. `WCFLibraryProject` is between Entity and WCF Application.
In `WCFLibraryProject` I described contract with all methods and data types WCFProject should use. (I mean WCFProject contract should be exactly the same). 
So is there a way to reference WCFProject contract to `WCFLibraryProject` contract?? - to use that somehow??
As I'm new code sample would be really helpful. 
Thanks A lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a a reference in the `WCFProject` to the `WCFLibraryProject` in order for the interfaces you defined to be exposed as the endpoints of `WCFProject`. The only thing the `WCFProject` should contain itself is a WCFProject.svc file to physically access your service.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx, the svc file could look like this:

```
<% @ServiceHost language="c#" Debug="true" Service="YourNameSpace.WCFLibraryProject" %>
```

Hosting this service in the default site of local IIS would show a html page with an access link to the metadata of your service at: http://localhost/WCFProject.svc.